# Symfony2 - Set translation domain for a whole form

Tags: symfony, localization

I want to translate a form created with symfony's formbuilder. As i don't want one big translation file it is [splitted up](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains) into "domains".

Now i have to specify the `translation_domain` for each form-field, otherwise symfony will look in the wrong file. This option has to be added to every field and i'm wondering if there is a way to set this option to a whole form?

**Sample code i'm not happy with:**

```
$builder->add(
    'author_name',
    'text',
    array('label' => 'Comment.author_name', 'translation_domain' => 'comment')
)->add(
    'email',
    'email',
    array('label' => 'Comment.email', 'translation_domain' => 'comment')
)->add(
    'content',
    'textarea',
    array('label' => 'Comment.content', 'translation_domain' => 'comment')
);
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've then to set it as a default option of your form, add this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{    
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'translation_domain' => 'comment'
    ));

}
```

to your `setDefaultOptions` method, in your form.

**Update:** It is deprecated. Use configureOptions method instead (thanks @Sudhakar Krishnan)

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgotten it b/c never needed it before.

Comment: What about on a form created without a class ?

Comment: Now it is deprecated. Use configureOptions method instead

Answer (score 26):

The method name in [Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649811/ahmed-siouani)'s answer is now deprecated (since Symfony 2.7), the 2.7+ way of doing it is:

```
/**
 * Configures the options for this type.
 *
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options.
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('translation_domain', 'messages');
}
```

in the same way you set your `data_class` settings, etc.

To do this using just the form builder, there is an `options` argument on the form builder. From the controller, for example:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity, ['translation_domain' => 'messages'])->add(..)->getForm();
```

If you're using the `FormFactory` service, this would be

```
$formFactory->createBuilder('form', $entity, ['translation_domain' => 'messages']);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Symfony 3

```
/**
 * Configures the options for this type.
 *
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options.
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        // Add more defaults if needed
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in case you use the Factory's namedBuilder that would be:

```
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('myForm', 'form', $data, array(
    'translation_domain' => 'forms',
));
```