# Symfony2 - list of translated values

Tags: symfony, combobox, translation

I'm using symfony2.4 + sonata + gedmo + a2 lix 1.x

I have one entity name "propriete" with his own translation entity (AbstractPersonalTranslation)

I'm able to create a admin form to CRUD the entity with translation tab (OK).

Now I want to display a part (filter on famille for instance) of the translated values of Propriete in an other admin form.

**I tried to create a QueryBuilder**

```
->add('firingTypes', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Sal\RefBundle\Entity\Propriete',
    'query_builder' => function(ProprieteRepository $er) {
     return $er->queryMyProprieteEn('u');
   }))
```

**From repository:**

```
   public function queryMyProprieteEn() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere("u.famille=:famille")
            ->setParameter("famille", "139");

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
    $query->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, 'en');

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But of course I have the following error "Expected argument of type Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given"

**How to handle to create a combobox/checkbox of translated values from a main form ?**

Please help

Regards

Comment: In the actual form, you can set the translation domain. See [translation_domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095592/symfony2-set-translation-domain-for-a-whole-form). You would only translate when it's rendered, not on the query?

Comment: Hi George, thank you for your reply, since my message I changed to https://github.com/Prezent/doctrine-translatable-bundle that fit to my need. brgds