# Symfony2 Set translation domain for a whole form without a class

Tags: symfony

I want to translate a form created with symfony's formbuilder.
Now i have to specify the translation_domain for each form-field.
This option has to be added to every field and i'm wondering if there is a way to set this option to a whole form?

**I need the solution for a form without a class.** I know the solution for a Form Type Class.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'translation_domain' => 'main'
    ));
```

This is my Code:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('shopChoiceForm')
        ->add('shops', 'entity', array('class' => 'AcmeBundle:Shop', 'choices' => $choices, 'translation_domain' => 'main'))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Choose', 'translation_domain' => 'main'))
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Set translation domain for a whole form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095592/symfony2-set-translation-domain-for-a-whole-form)

Comment: no possible duplicate, because i need the solution for a Form created through `$this->createFormBuilder()`

Comment: You need to post your code and your question. Not just copy-paste it from another question and say: "I need B instead of A"

Comment: it is in logic the same code? why should i retype all of it? Now i added my code in hope you will be satisfied.

Comment: It is much better. SO is a community-driven site. And all questions must be unique. If you have no time to formulate your question why do you think others will spend their valuable time to understand your question and answer it? It is disrespect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify translation domain in the twig at the moment you render your form. For doing so just use next code:

```
{% trans_default_domain "main" %}
```

It will change default translation domain to `main`. And it will influence only current template. If you want to render many forms in one template you can use `form_theme` tag and import theme with just this one line.

You can specify translation domain in the options array passed to the `createNamedBuilder()` as:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('shopChoiceForm', 'form', null, array('translation_domain' => 'main'))
    ->add('shops', 'entity', array('class' => 'AcmeBundle:Shop', 'choices' => $choices))
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Choose'))
    ->getForm();
```